How to solve the Android SDK not found issue. It says Android SDK version found: N/A version supported:34.0.0
When trying to build my React Native application using npx react-native run-android, I encountered an error that I've been unable to resolve for the past two days. Here's a breakdown of what I've tried and the details of the issue:
Error Screenshot: Error Screenshot
System Variables Configuration: System Variables Configuration
Required Paths: Required Paths
Additional Information:

I've set the Android SDK path in local.properties as follows:
sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\mypc\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk



Despite following advice from various sources including AI suggestions, Stack Overflow answers, and thorough checks of my environment configurations, the issue persists.
Could anyone provide insights or steps to resolve this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am not familiar with Windows when it comes to paths, but should it be like one backslash?  sdk.dir = C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Thanks, but After enabling Hyper-V from Windows features, my application started working. However, a new problem emerged where the build process gets stuck at 97%. I've tried troubleshooting since yesterday, attempting various solutions including checking the internet connection, restarting the system, and reinstalling npm dependencies, but none have resolved the issue. Even after waiting for 20 minutes during each attempt, the build remains stuck at 97%. Can you help me in this?
